# Is there any way to fetch UsageType and capacityStatus of a Instance. For now just for an Ec2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

To get the price of an instance, AWS provides the AWS Pricing API. But we need to use filtering to fetch the exact price for an instance.

I used Instance-type, tenancy, availability-zone and so on parameters to filter price.

I need to know, Is there any way to get UsageType and capacity-Status of an instance so that I can filter for more accurate results.
I don't want to **Hard-code** values for these types. Every value I want from the AWS APIs(means from AWS instances in my account).

Looked everywhere, not able to find this specific information.

UsageType is a filter option in Cost Explorer. 
AWS Pricing file csv/Json will also be having these parameters.

1. capacity-Status
2. UsageType

I need to get values of UsageType and capacity-Status from an instance to map with the parameters in the pricing file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are asking how to retrieve AWS Pricing API **attributes** from existing resources.

There are no API calls that can provide this information, but you could construct it.

For example, to discover the values available for `UsageType` on an Amazon EC2 instances, I used the [AWS CLI `get-attribute-values` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/pricing/get-attribute-values.html):

```
aws pricing get-attribute-values \
    --service-code AmazonEC2 \
    --attribute-name usagetype \
    --max-items 2 \
    --region us-east-1
```

This returned:

```
{
    "AttributeValues": [
        {
            "Value": "APE1-BoxUsage:c5.18xlarge"
        },
        {
            "Value": "APE1-BoxUsage:c5.2xlarge"
        }
    ],
    "NextToken": "..."
}
```

(The request asked for a maximum of 2 values.)

The `APE1` portion refers to [the region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/aws-usage-report-understand.html).

The `BoxUsage` part refers to whether the cost is on-demand, reserved, etc. Sample values are `BoxUsage`, `Reservation`, `DedicatedRes`, `UnusedBox`. They are listed on [On-Demand Capacity Reservations - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage-cr.html). If your instances are normal On-Demand instances, the use `BoxUsage` (I think).

The `capacityStatus` value also seems related to reserved instances.

Running this command:

```
aws pricing get-attribute-values \
    --service-code AmazonEC2 \
    --attribute-name capacitystatus \
    --region us-east-1
```

returned:

```
{
    "AttributeValues": [
        {
            "Value": "AllocatedCapacityReservation"
        },
        {
            "Value": "AllocatedHost"
        },
        {
            "Value": "NA"
        },
        {
            "Value": "UnusedCapacityReservation"
        },
        {
            "Value": "Used"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would assume that on-demand instances would use `NA`, but you should check your actual results for that.

**Bottom line:** You can retrieve possible attribute values with `get-attribute-values`, but you'll have to figure out which ones map to the instances you are running. There is no method for retrieving the appropriate values from running instances. They are merely billing attributes and are not directly associated with running instances. (They are calculated separately.)